# Data-type mismatch Access 2010

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access-2010

We have been creating a HR Database using Access as the back-end and Excel as the front-end. When I run my macro in Excel to insert entries into the MasterTable it says; "Data Type Mismatch". The only field that I had changed was the "Job" Field which required a value between `0.0` - `1.0` (i.e. `0.2` means they are only working one day).

Previously when I inserted entries in the decimal place would not show until I changed the field type in Access to accept decimals. After this change, the macro no longer works.

Can anyone point out why this is?

I have only just started learning SQL/Access so it is very likely I made a very basic mistake.

I searched up on SO a few other answers which talked about using the DECIMAL field instead of changing the properties field but this didn't solve my issue. My code:

```
    Sub ExportDataToAccess()

    Dim cn As Object
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim Id As String
    Dim Positions As String
    Dim BU As String
    Dim Job As Double
    Dim Variance As String
    Dim myDB As String

    'Initialize Variables
    Id = Worksheets("test").Range("A2").Value
    Positions = Worksheets("test").Range("B2").Value
    BU = Worksheets("test").Range("C2").Value
    Job = Worksheets("test").Range("D2").Value
    myDB = "X:\Users\ADMIN\Documents\HR_Establishment_DB1.accdb"
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"    'For *.ACCDB Databases
        .ConnectionString = myDB 'Connects to my DB
        .Open
    End With


    strQuery = "INSERT INTO MasterTable ([Id], [Positions], [BU], [Job]) " & _
               "VALUES (""" & Id & """, """ & Positions & """, """ & BU & """, " & Job & "); "

    cn.Execute strQuery
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing


    End Sub
```

[image: Excel Snapshot]
[image: Access Structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you intend the value of *ID* to be obtained from the excel (`Id = Worksheets("test").Range("A2").Value`)?

I think it is causing the error. If a field on access is of AutoNumber data type, you don't have to include it on your INSERT query as access automatically assigns a value for this in incremental manner.

If you want access to automatically assign a value for *ID*, change this:

```
    strQuery = "INSERT INTO MasterTable ([Id], [Positions], [BU], [Job]) " & _
           "VALUES (""" & Id & """, """ & Positions & """, """ & BU & """, " & Job & "); "
```

to this:

```
     strQuery = "INSERT INTO MasterTable ([Positions], [BU], [Job]) " & _
           "VALUES (""" & Positions & """, """ & BU & """, " & Job & "); "
```

Comment: Job has the data type Number with a field size of "double" and is accepting up to 4 Decimal Places.

Comment: have you tried casting your job variable to double? Try changing this: 'Job = Worksheets("test").Range("D2").Value' to this: 'Job = CDbl(Worksheets("test").Range("D2").Value)'

Comment: Hi Danielle, I tried that as well and it's the same error still. :(

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on _cn.Execute strQuery_ and take note of the value of _strQuery_ and post it here?

Comment: strQuery = "INSERT INTO MasterTable ([Id], [Positions], [BU], [Job]) VALUES ("", "Business Analyst", "Finance", 0.8); " And then it breaks at that point for reasons unknown.

Comment: can you also post the structure of _ID_, _Positions_, and _BU_

Comment: ID - Automated Number, Positions (String), BU (String)

Comment: Hi Danielle, I actually included the number field and had it populated - and it FINALLY inserts now. I didn't realize that because I had the type set as AUTO Populate, I don't need to insert data. But because in my insert statement I still referenced ID, it chucked an error message because It was inserting "NULL" values in the ID area. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad to have helped you! :)